# AWS CodeDeploy Multiple Application deployment Synchronized

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to find a solution for deployment in codeDeploy.
I need to get to the point where I'll deploy nine services. In a synchronized way, if one fails, it will be possible to do a rollback for everyone.

They are all in the same cluster.

The deployment group cannot use more than one service. And in one application it will be not possible to deploy several services together.